# Django - Why Sweetify is not working. SweetAlert2

Tags: django, django-templates, alert, django-class-based-views, sweetalert2

I'm followed the documentation from [Atrox](https://github.com/Atrox/sweetify-django), and then still not working on my project.
Any Idea ?

I write the code like below.

**1. home/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic import FormView
from attendance.models import Graduates
from home.forms import TicketForm
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
import sweetify

class HomeView(FormView):
template_name = 'home/index.html'
form_class = TicketForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    getId = form.cleaned_data['nomor_ticket']      
    
    try:
        graduate = Graduates.objects.get(ticket_id=getId)
        message_success = 'Congratulations'

        if graduate:
            graduate.attendance = timezone.now()
            graduate.status = True
            graduate.save()
            sweetify.success(self.request, message_success, text='Cool', persistent='Thanks', timer='3000')
            return (redirect('attendance:index', graduate.ticket_id))

    except Graduates.DoesNotExist:
        print('ticket not found')
        return redirect('home:index')
```

**2. templates/base.html**

```
...
<body>
  {% block contents %}{% endblock contents %}
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.5.3/dist/flowbite.js"></script>
  {% load sweetify %}
  {% sweetify %}
</body>
...
```

**3. core/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'sweetify'
...
]

SWEETIFY_SWEETALERT_LIBRARY = 'sweetalert2'
```

Comment: your code just need to add cdn which is i added in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here done with this code

#### ------- base.html ---------

```
{% load static %}

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
        {% block title %}
                                      
        {% endblock title %}
    </title>
</head>
<body>
  
  {% block body %}
   
  {% endblock body %}
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/11.6.5/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
  

</body>
</html>


{% load sweetify %}
{% sweetify %}
```

#### Output with bowser

[image]

Comment: it still not working

Comment: answer is updated check it